# How can I annotate a trimodal historgram using pandas hist?

Tags: python, plot, histogram, mode

I am plotting a column of my dataframe as a historgram. When i plot it i can see that there are 3 peaks, so it is trimodal. How can i annotate my diagram to label each peak with it's value?

my code below plots two histograms side by side one is of the datafarme with outliers and the second is the dataframe without.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(10,4))

df['price'].hist(bins=40,ax=ax[0])
df_nooutlier['price'].hist(bins=40,ax=ax[1])
df_nooutlier['price'].value_counts().head().plot(kind='line',linestyle='None', marker='o',color='r') #how can i plot such that i can see the labels
```

i want each peak to be labelled with it's frequency

Answer (score 2):

The following approach is to find the modes and their indices (i.e. x and y values to plot a dot and text at). It uses `np.histogram` to get the distribution counts and bin divisions corresponding to the histogram.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def get_random_prices():
    """sample from three normal distributions"""
    dist1 = np.random.normal(loc=5, scale=.3, size=1000)
    dist2 = np.random.normal(loc=7, scale=.3, size=1000)
    dist3 = np.random.normal(loc=11, scale=.3, size=1000)
    min_price, max_price = 0, 20
    all_dist = np.concatenate([dist1, dist2, dist3])
    return all_dist[all_dist >= min_price][all_dist <= max_price]

def get_modes(counts, min_sep=.5):
    # simple method to get mode values and locations (indexes)
    # assume counts are already smoothed
    # assume last mode is not past penultimate spot
    modes = []
    max_ct = 0
    increasing = True
    for i, count in enumerate(counts[1:]):
        if count >= counts[i]:
            max_ct = count
            increasing = True
        elif increasing:
            modes.append((max_ct, i))
            max_ct = 0
            increasing = False
    return modes

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# create randomly generated data
df = pd.DataFrame({'price': get_random_prices()})

# get histogram data and display the same histogram
n_bins = 40
counts, divisions = np.histogram(df['price'], bins=n_bins)
df['price'].hist(bins=n_bins)

# find the peaks
modes = get_modes(counts)

# add the dots and labels for each peak, onto the histogram object
for mode, mode_index in modes:
    ax.plot(divisions[mode_index], mode, 'ro')
    # use offsets to make text appear away from the dots
    # probably write logic to determine this instead of hard-coding
    offset_x, offset_y = .1, 2
    ax.text(divisions[mode_index] + offset_x, mode + offset_y, mode, color='r')
```

The following displayed with `modes` equal to `[(229, 5), (248, 15), (239, 35)]`, and `np.__version__, pd.__version__` were `('1.16.2', '0.24.2')`:

[image: sample histogram]

Comment: when i run this it says i can't assign to literal? .1, 2 = offset_x, offset_y <-- this part

Comment: Oops, that was a typo. Updated to offset_x, offset_y = .1, 2